Tried commands to make my bluetooth work on my terminal but nothing works
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
Failed to restart bluetooth.service: 
Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, 
please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
See system logs and 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.


original title 'j'ai pratiquement essayer toute les commandes pour faire fonctionner mon bluetooth sur mon terminal mais rien ne marche"

Please do as asked: systemctl status bluetooth.service  if unsure what the problem is add the results to the question please.

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Can you edit the question to add results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
